# Table UNION if Foreign key value is null on table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables that I'm trying to combine.

Table 1:

```
FAME_ID, FAME_Emblem_Title, FAME_Category
```

Table 2:

```
User_ID, FAME_ID, Times_Received
```

However, some values does not exist in table 2. For Example:

```
Table 1:                        Table 2:
Fame_ID: 1                      Fame_ID: null/does not have a value
FAME_Emblem_Title: test1        User_ID: null/does not have a value
FAME_Category: 1                Times_Received: null/does not have a value

Fame_ID: 2                      Fame_ID: 2
FAME_Emblem_Title: test2        User_ID: user1
FAME_Category: 1                Times_Received: 1
```

My goal is to filter the SQL query by Category and user but still display all results that match the first filter even if table 2 does not have any value. By the way my output is in JSON array form.

Result:

```
[
  {
    "User_ID": "user1",
    "FAME_ID": 1,
    "FAME_Category": "1",
    "Times_Received": 1,
   },
  {
    "User_ID": "null",
    "FAME_ID": 2,
    "FAME_Category": "1",
    "Times_Received": null,
   }
]
```

I'm honestly not sure if this is possible. Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The JOIN required when you want to return all rows from the LEFT table even if there is no join to the RIGHT table is called a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx). If there is no match, then the row for the left table will be returned, and the value `null` substitude for all columns of the missing right table row.

You can achieve the join you want as follows, and output in [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) with:

```
SELECT t2.User_ID, t1.FAME_ID, t1.FAME_Category, t2.Times_Received
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.FAME_ID = t2.FAME_ID
FOR JSON AUTO;
```